# R Studio tinytex::tlmgr_update() gets an error

Tags: r, latex, tinytex

When I try to run:

```
tinytex::tlmgr_update()
```

I get the following error:
[image]

Not sure what to do next, any advice?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/69 and/or https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/210?

Comment: I did, but for example if I run tinytex::tlmgr_install(c('texlive-scripts', 'dehyph-exptl')) it keeps complaining Cannot run wrapper due to missing luatex.dll

Comment: Not sure if this is an ongoing issue? https://github.com/edquant/edh7916/issues/26

Comment: TeXLive broke a couple of days ago, apparently. Yihui says the issue here can be tracked at https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/210. Notable is that a common fix (`tinytex:::install_prebuilt()`) ***will not solve this***, there is no fix within `tinytex` until TeXLive upstream fixes it. If you are in need of knitting to PDF, a workaround is to [install MiKTeX](https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex).

Comment: MilesMorales, a [recent comment](https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/210#issuecomment-629407771) suggests a way to update tinytex with a specific repo. Could you please test that method to see if it fixes your issue? (And please report back with good/bad news.) Thanks!

Comment: I have MiKTeX installed, but still get the same errors, also have tried with a specific repo but doesn't recognize install_tinytext() as a valid function

Comment: *"doesn't recognize install_tinytext()"* could be due to either (a) you mis-typed it, and it should be `install_tinytex()` (no trailing `t`), or (b) either use `tinytex:...` or first do `library(tinytex)`.

Comment: sorry tried editing my comment but was too soon, yes I did tinytex::install_tinytex(force =T, 'https://www.ctan.org/mirrors/mirmon') and still got the same error

Comment: Okay ... I haven't tested it, but there have been several more comments (at issue [tinytex#210](https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/210)) since then that suggest is has worked for others. I'm not an expert on it, just an option.

Comment: BTW: you didn't name your second argument, you might need to *name* `repository='ctan.org/mirrorws/mirmon'` (the second arg is `dir=`).

Comment: @r2evans no need, but I tried both ways still same error.

Comment: It seems the workaround now is to use the prebuild after uninstalling, as the prebuild package has just been updated.

Comment: I think you're approaching (or "at") the point where you can self-answer with the offered workaround, and potentially come back in a day or a week with an "edit: it's been resolved" kind of note to your answer. I don't know that I've offered much more than a link to the github issue where the real progress has been made.